# Issue animating sprites C#

Tags: c#, animation, sprite

I'm painting an image with `e.Graphics.DrawImage` in the `Form_Paint()` event. I use a `Timer` to refresh the form. The problem is that the animation blinks. It seems that it is taking too long to update `e`. I have 2 `PictureBox` inside the Form.

Ideas?

UPDATE:

```
    public Bitmap Paint(int state, Graphics g)
    {
        this.state = state;

        Bitmap temp;
        Graphics tempGraphics;
        temp = new Bitmap(45, 47, g);
        tempGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(temp);

        switch (state)
        {
            case 0:
                tempGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(img, x, y);
                break;

            case 1:
                tempGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(img, x, y - 42);
                break;
        }
    }
```

This prepares the sprite before adding it to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by avoiding doing any animation on the form itself. If you add controls to a form and then you animate the parent, you over-do the UI thread. The best solution was keeping all the animations in pictureboxes.

So: you either animate directly with `g.DrawImage()` or you stick to using `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 1):

The way this is generally managed is by drawing the update to an in-memory bitmap. And then drawing the bitmap to the screen. The processes is slower (because there's more to do), but it looks faster because there's no flicker.

However, many controls will actually do this for you automatically. Look into [double buffering techniques](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/07/20/use-double-buffering-to-reduce-flicker-on-a-single-picturebox-in-c.aspx).

Comment: I am already using .doublebuffering = true. Maybe the GUI thread is too busy taking care of the picture boxes?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know what your code does. You might also check if your background is being cleared to a different color before final painting. Either way, I've done double buffering in many different ways and many different languages, and I can assure you that, if done right, there will be no flicker. Did you already read the article I referenced?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it caused by not setting styles properly and as result background is drawn first (usually white) and then your image.

Also search/read on double-buffering if simply drawing ones is not fast enough.